# how to set portrait mode only in our iphone app?

Tags: iphone, orientation, portrait

i am getting a strange problem in my iPhone app. I want my app to support ONLY portrait mode, but for some reason I can't do it (device & simulator).

To support only portrait mode I did as follow:

```
In the TARGET summary section on Xcode, I chose only portrait.
All my ViewControllers implements shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

But as I said it won't work, and the strange result is that the app support ALL the orientations (portrait, upside down, landscape left, landscape right).
Any ideas?

this how I implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     NSLog(@"Checking orientation %d", interfaceOrientation);
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Sir,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Hope It helps.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

set the key "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)" with which orientation you want  in info.plist file of your app.

Here I am using only Landscape you can use Portrait.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you then click on accept check and up arrow that will also help you to quickly answer your questions.